# canonical map of a monoid to its classifying space

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces, loop-spaces

- Every monoid $M$ is a category with one object $M$ and morphisms the elements of $M$. [Martin Brandenburg.]
- Every small category $C$ has a classifying space $BC$, defined as the geometric realization of the [nerve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_%28category_theory%29). [Martin Brandenburg.]
- The classifying space $BM$ of a monoid $M$ is (by definition) the classifying space  of the corresponding category.[Martin Brandenburg.]

In [Homology Fibrations and the "Group-Completion" 
Theorem. 
McDuff, D.; Segal, G.](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/mcdsegal.pdf), line 2, "there is a canonical map of $H$-spaces from $M\to \Omega BM$ from $M$ to the space of loops on $BM$". What is this canonical map?

Comment: Probably the unit of some adjunction, bar/cobar or something similar. That's what I'd guess.

Comment: Unless $M$ is discrete, the classifying space of $M$ will not coïncide with the classifying space of the one object category with morphisms $M$. A different construction is done for topological groups and is known under thename [Milnor construction / Milnor Classifying space](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Milnor+construction), and there are similar constructions for $H$-spaces due (I think) to Stascheff. In any case, my point is that the authors are likely using a different construction of the classifying space than that of the classifying space of the one object category with morphisms $M$.

Comment: Dear Prof. Zhen, could you tell me more about the canonical map?

Comment: Giving a continuous map $f : M \to \Omega B M$ is the same thing as giving a continuous map $g : M \times S^1 \to B M$ that is basepoint-preserving in the second variable. If you build $B M$ using the bar construction, there is an obvious such map.

Comment: Dear Prof. Zhen, what is the bar construction of $BM$? Is there any reference not too difficult to understand? Thanks!

Comment: It is essentially what Martin Brandenburg mentions in his answer. Have you understood _that_?

Comment: @RSQ: The first lines of your question are copied almost verbatim from my recent answer on $BM$. Please quote or reference accordingly!

Comment: Sorry Prof. Martin Brandenburg.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $M$ be a topological monoid. $M$ can be considered as a category internal to topological spaces and has a simplicial space $N_\bullet(M)$ as its nerve. (It's also called the internal nerve.) The geometric realization $BM=|N_\bullet(M)|$ of this simplicial space is the classifying space $BM$. (This includes the discrete case.)

Unveiling the definitions, it is given by $$BM=(\coprod\limits_{n\ge0}M^n\times\Delta^n)/\tilde{}.$$

Now for each element $m\in M$,

Now for each element $m\in M$, one gets an obvious map $$\Delta^1\rightarrow M\times\Delta^1\rightarrow BM,$$ which factors over $S^1\cong\Delta^1/\partial\Delta^1,$ so one gets a loop in $BM$. Putting all those together yields the canonical map $M\rightarrow\Omega BM$.

This is the same thing both for the standard and the so-called fat geometric realization of simplicial spaces. The latter one is the one used in the McDuff-Segal paper.

---

Edit: RSQ asked for a more detailed description of the "obvious map". I'll try to be as detailed as possible.

Recall the definition of the standard n simplex $$\Delta^n=\{(x_0,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}|\sum_{i=0}^nx_i=1, 0\le x_i\le1\}$$ Let $m\in M$ and define $$l_m\colon \Delta^1\rightarrow BM$$ as the composition of $$\Delta^1\rightarrow M\times\Delta^1,(t_0,t_1)\mapsto(m,t_0,t_1)$$ the inclusion $$M\times\Delta^1\rightarrow \coprod\limits_{n\ge0}M^n\times\Delta^n$$ and the quotient map $$\coprod\limits_{n\ge0}M^n\times\Delta^n\rightarrow BM=(\coprod\limits_{n\ge0}M^n\times\Delta^n)/\tilde{}.$$ By precomposing with the homeomorphism $$[0,1]\rightarrow \Delta^1,t\mapsto(t,(1-t))$$ we get a path $$[0,1]\rightarrow BM$$ which I'll call $l_m$, too. Now we want to see that this is actually a loop: It holds $$l_m(0)=[m,(0,1)]=[e,0]=[m,(1,0)]=l_m(1)$$ where $[\_]$ denotes equivalence classes in $BM$ and the second and the third equality follows from the relations $\tilde{}$ we imposed on $BM$ (You can find them in any text about simplicial sets or simplicial spaces.). It follows that $l_m$ factors as $$S^1=[0,1]/\{0,1\}\rightarrow BM,$$ which I'll call $l_m$, too. Now finally define $$M\rightarrow \Omega BM, m\mapsto l_m.$$

Comment: @RSQ Please do not edit answers by inserting questions. You can ask your question to an answer as a comment below the answer.

Comment: Dear Prof., sorry for asking in your answers. I will remember your instructions and never ask in answers from now on.

Comment: As you can read in my profile, I'm not a professor, but a simple student.

Comment: thanks so much. Moreover, I have another question:

Comment: Let $M$ be a monoid and $BM$ be its classifying space. There is a model for $BM$ based on labelled configuration spaces of the line $[0,1]$. Points of the configurations are labelled by elements of $m$. The topology is such that points can fall off or move in from the boundary. If points meet, then they come together and the labels multiply. The map $M \rightarrow \Omega BM$ takes an element of $m$ and maps it to the loop that introduces a configuration point labelled by $m$ at $0$ and moves it along the interval until it falls off at  $1$. This is actually a map of monoids

Comment: (cf. https://twoplusonet.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/notes-on-the-group-completion-theorem/). Why we have such a model? Is there any proof or references?