# universal bundle of topological monoids

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups, geometric-topology, fibration, classifying-spaces

Let $M$ be a topological monoid. There is a classifying space $BM$ (cf. [canonical map of a monoid to its classifying space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313289/canonical-map-of-a-monoid-to-its-classifying-space)). When $M$ is a group $G$, there is a principal $G$-bundle $EG\to BG$ such that $EG\simeq *$. For general topological monoid, is there such a space $EM$ and a map $$
p: EM\to BM$$ such that $p^{-1}(b)\simeq M$ for each $b\in BM$?